# Как синхронизировать отправку сообщения одной стороной и обработку его другой стороной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, синхронизация, семафоры

Есть параллельно работающий consumer, который получает сообщения и как-то их обрабатывает. Необходимо написать функцию, отправляющую ему сообщения и ожидающую их обработки. При этом:

- На отправку должен быть таймаут. Т.е., если consumer за время таймаута не успел принять и обработать сообщение, то функция send должна бросить исключение `TimeoutError`
- При срабатывании таймаута должно произойти:

  - consumer должен прекратить обработку сообщения, если он успел его принять
  - сообщение должно быть удалено из канала

Условный код:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import random
from itertools import count


# Канал для передачи сообщений
messages_queue = Queue(1)


def consumer_thread():  # Потребитель, работающий независимо
    while True:
        if random.random() < 0.05:  # Неизвестно, когда он готов будет получить сообщение
            msg = messages_queue.get()  # Получение сообщения
            print(f'got {msg}')
            time.sleep(0.5)  # Какая-то его обработка
            # Тут надо как-то оповестить производителя, что сообщение обработано
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)


def send(msg, timeout=0.5):  # Функция отправки сообщения с таймаутом
    # Вот тут необходимо запустить какой-то таймер
    # Который будет отсчитывать время с момента начала отправки сообщения
    messages_queue.put(msg)
    # До момента оповещения потребителем, что он обработал сообщение
    
    # Если таймер превысил таймаут, то необходимо:
    # * Прекратить обработку сообщения потребителем, если он начал
    # * Очистить очередь
    # * Бросить исключение таймаута


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=consumer_thread).start()
    
    for i in count():
        msg = f'msg{i}'

        print(f'trying to send {msg}')
        try:
            send(msg)
        except TimeoutError:
            print(f'Не удалось отправить {msg}')
```

У меня получалось реализовать таймаут с очищением очереди, но это решение, к сожалению, нигде не сохранилось, воспроизвести сейчас его не получается и оно не захватывало случай, когда сообщение уже забралось из очереди. Т.е., возбуждался TimeoutError, но сообщение всё равно отправлялось.

---

Зачем это нужно: для последовательной отправки сообщений по websocket. Поток consumer'а отвечает за взаимодействие с ws сервером, т.е., он:

- Принимает сообщения от ws сервера и складывает их в очередь полученных сообщений - тут проблем нет. Принял - положил.
- Отправляет сообщения из очереди на ws сервер - вот тут необходимо реализовать таймаут на отправку, т.к. он, например, может быть "занят" только получением сообщений и может не дойти до отправки.

---

По [наводке @eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1238733/324059) получился такой код:

```py
import random
import time
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue
from itertools import count

msg_queue = Queue(1)


def consumer_thread():
    while True:
        if random.random() < 0.2:  # Не всегда готов обработать сообщение
            msg, ready, canceled = msg_queue.get()  # type: str, Event, Event
            print(f'[C] {msg} получено')
            if canceled.is_set():
                continue
            time.sleep(random.random())  # Как будто обрабатываем сообщение
            print(f'[C] {msg} обработано')
            ready.set()
        else:
            time.sleep(random.random())


def send(msg, timeout=0.5):
    ready = Event()
    canceled = Event()
    msg_queue.put((msg, ready, canceled))

    if not ready.wait(timeout):
        canceled.set()

    if canceled.is_set():
        with msg_queue.mutex:
            msg_queue.queue.clear()
        raise TimeoutError


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=consumer_thread).start()

    for i in count():
        msg = f'msg{i}'
        print(f'[P] Пытаюсь отправить {msg}...')
        try:
            send(msg)
        except TimeoutError:
            print(f'[P] Не удалось отправить {msg}')
        else:
            print(f'[P] {msg} отправлено')
```

Но возникают ситуации, когда producer говорит, что не удалось отправить сообщение, а consumer говорит, что оно обработано:

```
[P] Пытаюсь отправить msg5...
[C] msg5 получено
[P] Не удалось отправить msg5
[P] Пытаюсь отправить msg6...
[C] msg5 обработано
```

Comment: А почему размер очереди = 1?

Comment: @mkkik Это не принципиально. 1 выбрал потому что передавать надо по одному сообщению и нет смысла делать очередь размером больше, чем 1.

Answer (score 1):

Оповестить производителя можно через `messages_queue.task_done()` или `threading.Event`

На производителе через `messages_queue.join(timeout)` - дожидаемся получения сообщения.

Вот отменить задание более интересная задача. Предлагаю добавить threading.Lock(), а к задаче прилепить флаг.

```
canceled_flag=[]
messages_queue.put((msg, canceled_flag))
messages_queue.join(1)
with canceled_lock:
    canceled_flag.append(True)
if canceled_flag[0] is True:
   raise TimeoutError
```

и

```
msg, canceled_flag = messages_queue.get()
messages_queue.task_done()
with canceled_lock:
    canceled_flag.append(False)

if canceled_flag[0] is False:
   do_work
```

Через Event наверное лучше будет - не нужна конструкция с блоком.

```
ready = threading.Event()
canceled = threading.Event()
messages_queue.put(msg, ready, canceled)
try:
    ready.wait(timeout)
except:
    canceled.set()

if canceled.is_set(): raise TimeoutError
```

и

```
msg, ready, canceled = messages_queue.get()
ready.set()
if canceled.is_set(): 
    continue
else:
    do_work()
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, но в данном режиме consumer уведомляет producer о том, что он **начал** обрабатывать сообщение, а не закончил. Если же `ready.set()` вынести за `do_work()`, то возможна ситуация, когда producer не выставил `cancelled`, а у consumer'а уже `if` прошёл, что приводит к тому, что бросился таймаут, но сообщение обработалось.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я думал тут про актуальность перед стартом. Во время работы поймать исключение для отмены в треде сложновато.